# Why threads created with `_thread.start_new_thread` don't print anything?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I found this simple code at https://code.google.com/p/pyloadtools/wiki/CodeTutorialMultiThreading

```
import _thread

def hello(num):
    print('hello from thread %s\n' % num)

_thread.start_new_thread(hello, (0,))
_thread.start_new_thread(hello, (1,))
_thread.start_new_thread(hello, (2,))
```

But when I run this, it works on IDLE, but not on eclipse which uses PyDev.  Any idea how to fix it?

**Note**:  I think the main program terminates before the threads run. The threads dont get enough time to run I guess. How do I fix it? May be should I use join?

Comment: How does it not work? What is the error?

Comment: `May be should I use join?` - Unfortunately, it is not available in the low-level `_thread` API. You should use `threading` module, or resort to make the main thread wait for the child threads to exit, like I have shown in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the `Caveats` section of [`_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/_thread.html) documentation,

> - When the main thread exits, it is system defined whether the other threads survive. On most systems, they are killed without executing `try ... finally` clauses or executing object destructors.
> - When the main thread exits, it does not do any of its usual cleanup (except that `try ... finally` clauses are honored), and the **standard I/O files are not flushed**.

There are two possibilities here.

1. The main thread starts three threads but it exits before the threads finish the execution. So, the standard I/O files are not flushed, [as they are buffered, by default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin).
2. Or, the main thread dies, and as per the first bullet point quoted, all the child threads are killed in action.

Either way, you need to make sure the main thread doesn't die before the children complete.

But when you run from IDLE, the main thread still exists, so, the I/O buffers are flushed when the threads actually complete. That is why it works in IDLE but not in eclipse.

---

To make sure that the main thread exits only after all the threads complete, you can make it wait for the child threads with

#### 1. [`Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects)

You can use `Semaphore`, like this

```
import _thread
import threading


def hello(num):
    print('hello from thread %s' % num)
    # Release semaphore when the thread is actually done
    sem.release()


def create_thread(value):
    # Acquire semaphore when the thread is actually created
    sem.acquire()
    _thread.start_new_thread(hello, (value,))

# Counting semaphore. Maximum three threads can acquire.
# Next acquire call has to wait till somebody releases
sem = threading.Semaphore(3)

for i in range(3):
    create_thread(i)

# We are capturing the semaphore three times again, because 
# whenever a thread completes it releases it. So, only when we 
# acquire it thrice to make sure that all threads have completed.
for i in range(3):
    sem.acquire()
```

#### [2. `Lock Objects`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html#_thread.allocate_lock)

Alternatively, you can use the `_thread.lock` objects, like this

```
import _thread

locks = []


def hello(num, lockobject):
    print('hello from thread %s' % num)
    # Release the lock as we are done here
    lockobject.release()


def create_thread(value):
    # Create a lock and acquire it
    a_lock = _thread.allocate_lock()
    a_lock.acquire()

    # Store it in the global locks list
    locks.append(a_lock)

    # Pass it to the newly created thread which can release the lock once done
    _thread.start_new_thread(hello, (value, a_lock))

for i in range(3):
    create_thread(i)

# Acquire all the locks, which means all the threads have released the locks
all(lock.acquire() for lock in locks)
```

Now you will see that the program always prints the `hello from` message.

---

**Note:** As the documentation says, `_thread` is a `Low-level threading API`. So, better use higher level module like [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading), where you can simply wait for the all the threads to exit with [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) method.

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html#module-_thread

> The `threading` module provides an easier to use and higher-level threading API built on top of this module.
>
> The module is optional.

So please use [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), not the *optional* `_thread` module.